# Filling a dataframe column based on multiple conditional choices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `data` which looks like:

```
Holiday  Report   Action     Power
0             0        0     1.345
0             0        0     1.345
1             0        0     0
0             0        0     1.345
0             0        0     1.345
0             1        0     0
0             0        0     1.345
0             1        1     0
0             0        0     1.345
0             0        1     0
```

Columns 'Holiday', 'Report' and 'Actions' are pulled in.  Power is calculated by looking a some other columns of data.  I am looking for a line of code that will allow me to set the power to zero if any of the columns 'Holiday', 'Report' or 'Actions' is set to 1.

I can do this procedure one column at a time:

```
data.loc[staticidx, "power"] = np.where(dayData.Holiday = 1, 0, (a - b)/(c-1))
data.loc[staticidx, "power"] = np.where(dayData.Report= 1, 0, (a - b)/(c-1))
data.loc[staticidx, "power"] = np.where(dayData.Actions= 1, 0, (a - b)/(c-1))
```

but is there a way to combine them into one function with something like an OR statement?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subselect the rows by slicing, compare against 1 and use `any` with param `axis=1` and create a boolean mask passing to `loc` to set only those rows that meet the condition to `1` as desired:

```
In [23]:
df.loc[(df.ix[:,:'Action'] == 1).any(axis=1), 'Power'] = 1
df

Out[23]:
   Holiday  Report  Action  Power
0        0       0       0  1.345
1        0       0       0  1.345
2        1       0       0  1.000
3        0       0       0  1.345
4        0       0       0  1.345
5        0       1       0  1.000
6        0       0       0  1.345
7        0       1       1  1.000
8        0       0       0  1.345
9        0       0       1  1.000
```

Comment: Perhaps something like : `np.where((df.ix[:,:'Action'] == 1).any(axis=1),0,1.345)`?

Comment: @Divakar that handles all rows, here using `loc` will only update the rows that meet the condition leaving any existing values untouched

Comment: Oh yes. So, I guess you can avoid that `>0` and the assignment needs to be `0` instead of `1`?

Comment: Well here `(df.ix[:,:'Action'] == 1).any(axis=1)` generates a boolean series, when you compare against `> 0` it'll upcast boolean values to int and compare against `0` to generate another boolean series to mask the rows

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps using `np.where`:

```
In[49]:df['Power']=np.where((df['Holiday']==1)|(df['Report']==1)|(df['Action']==1),1,df['Power'])

In[50]:df
Out[50]: 
   Holiday  Report  Action  Power
0        0       0       0  1.345
1        0       0       0  1.345
2        1       0       0  1.000
3        0       0       0  1.345
4        0       0       0  1.345
5        0       1       0  1.000
6        0       0       0  1.345
7        0       1       1  1.000
8        0       0       0  1.345
9        0       0       1  1.000
```